# Why does my game use 100% CPU and LunarLander doesn't?

Tags: android, performance

Well basically my question is right in the title: why does my game use 100% cpu and the LunarLander example does not?

My game is currently almost identical to the LunarLander example in function, with a separate thread for the game loop, updating physics/events in a while() loop and drawing to the screen continuously.

However when I run LunarLander and enable the debug tools, it shows about 50% cpu usage (the emulator uses about 25% on my dual-core PC). My own game uses 100% of the cpu (and the emulator 50% on my pc).

I don't necessarily want or need to reduce the cpu load and increase the performance of my game (although it runs a bit sluggish on the emulator and on a slower phone), but I just really don't understand why the LunarLander example doesn't use 100%? It basically has a while(true) loop in which it updates the physics and draws to the screen constantly. Why does that not reach 100%?

Also my game is quite similar: I update my game state in a method and then draw everything to the screen. First a background image, then a few other images on it (the LunarLander example uses Drawables while I use Bitmap, because I don't have to transform them and they're supposed to be faster). When I don't interact with the game, nothing even really happens, and interaction is done through events, not even in the main loop.

Any ideas? :-)

Comment: "My game is currently almost identical to the LunarLander example" - How is it different? Code would help a lot.

Comment: Well I could post a few thousand lines of code, but that would make nobody happy. It's different in that I load and draw other bitmaps. I have an ontouchlistener which sets an offset on moving to draw the background in another position. And I draw Bitmap tiles on it (from an ArrayList) rather than a Drawable which is transformed. And that's about it. The overall structure (thread for game loop, update() method, draw() method) is the same.

Comment: You probably do want to reduce the CPU load. The load you place on mobile hardware is directly related to how much of the user's battery power it will consume.

Answer (score 1):

The only way any thread can use less than 100% of its core is if it contains I/O, sleeps, competition with another thread, or anything that suspends it some of the time. So if you [pause the lunar lander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) a few times, you will see how it suspends.